# AngularJS: change parent scope value in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm a newbie to AngularJS. I would like to implement a custom directive that supports "alert" (or say "notification"), e.g. when I successfully update the user information, a small box will appear on the page that says "Your information has been successfully updated", and will disappear after 2 seconds or so.

Below is my current code (I'm using Bootstrap for the template, so the class "alert" is for that sake):

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('notification', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        type: '=', // the type of the notification, i.e. it can be success, can be error and so on
        condition: '=' // if condition is evaluated to true in the parent scope, this notification bar will appear
      },
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
        scope.$watch(scope.condition, function () {
          if (scope.condition) {
            $timeout(function () {
              scope.condition = false; // I wish to change the value in the parent scope
            }, 2000);
          }
        });
      },
      templateUrl: 'partials/notification'
    };
  }]);
```

In notification.jade (I'm using Jade as the templating engine):

```
!= "<div class='alert alert-{{ type }}' ng-transclude ng-show='condition'>"
!= "</div>"
```

And the actual use of this notification directive:

```
notification(type='"success"', condition='submissionSuccess')
  span Your information has been successfully updated.
```

What I want to do is as follows. In the parent $scope I have a variable called 'submissionSuccess', and it is set to true when the Ajax call to backend is successful. When it is true, I will show the notification bar (hence the ng-show='condition' in the Jade file), and I wish to hide this bar after some time (which is why I have the $timeout snippet in the directive configurations). However, there seems to be some bug. I cannot change the value of parent $scope.condition inside the custom directive, and therefore the notification bar isn't hidden automatically.

How should I solve this problem? Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how prototype-based scope inheritance works. During directive instantiation directive has to create it's own `condition` property within isolated scope. It doesn't have connection with parent scope here, because it's privitive value (true/false) defined in child scope. It has to do with that fact that primitive values sort of "shadows" parent prototype properties.

I would recommend to stick with more comprehensive and reliable object object references:

```
.directive('notification', ['$timeout',
    function($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                config: '='
            },
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
                scope.$watch('config.condition', function() {
                    if (scope.config && scope.config.condition) {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            scope.config.condition = false; // I wish to change the value in the parent scope
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                });
            },
            templateUrl: 'partials/notification.html'
        };
    }
]);
```

Then templates will become:

```
<div class="alert alert-{{ config.type }}" ng-transclude="" ng-show="config.condition"></div>
```

and

```
<notification config="config">
    Some message here.
</notification>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/M0iSjHwFXXEACWf79zW7?p=preview